IC identification MORNT A2001 1837
Please help me to identify this IC in MSOP-8 package.
MORNT
A2001
1837


While the question suggests the device in question is an IC, on a search looks to be a Vishay MORN which is a range of PRECISION INTEGRATED SURFACE-MOUNT RESISTORS.
The datasheet for the Molded, Compact, 0.65 mm Pitch, Dual-In-Line Thin Film Resistor, Surface-Mount Network 0.01 % Ratio Tolerance and 1 ppm/°C TCR Tracking has a picture which starts the identification as MORNA:

The DIMENSIONS AND IMPRINTING shows the marking lines:

Decoding the marking from the picture in the question:

The first line is MORNT is the global model which means Lead (Pb)-free) (e3)
The second line is A2001. I think the leading A means 4 isolated
equal resistors (albeit the datasheet marking doesn't indicate the A will be present on the second line). The 2001 is the resistance value. The first three digits are the significant figures, and the digit is the number of zeros to follow. So, for this device 2 KΩ.
The third line is the Date Code (of manufacturer).

The land pattern shown in the datasheet is for MSOP MO-187AA, which matches the MSOP-8 mentioned in the question.
